Should I implement a C# destructor (aka finalizer) to unsubscribe from a system event?
Answer to "duplicate" - while a weak event may be the best solution here. The question is very different.
In this answer we are told to (almost) never write a destructor by someone who worked on the C# compiler. We are also warned there are many pitfalls that way.
We are also suggested that the place to use it is when holding on to unmanaged resources.
And finally, that it's better to implement a disposable.
But there seems to be a simple case (which I currently ran into) which is to unsubscribe from system events (e.g. SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged ). It's not practical to use disposable since the whole reason to use a destructor is to prevent a caller forgetting to call Dispose, and using a using block is not appropriate in many cases.
From SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged:

Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.

So to sum up, I have a class which subscribes to a system event and then uses that information. At some point the class might not be referenced anymore and get garbage collected, but it won't know to unsubscribe from the system event. Is it really appropriate to unsubscribe in a destructor in this case? (And if so - what should my checklist be for avoiding the pitfalls?)
Obviously one shouldn't rely on a destructor. I mean create a destructor in case there's a bug in the caller code.
EDIT
The class instance will be eligible for collection, at least according to this answer. And another answer (by Skeet) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21750930/939213

maybe use the WeakEvent pattern instead? this seems useful

"using a using block is not appropriate in many cases." like when?

Using a finalizer would not work in this case. Such a finalizer would never be called whilst your object is subscribed to the event as the event handler subscription makes the object reachable (since the event is static) and so it would never become eligible for finalization.

@Iridium as the event handler subscription makes the object reachable... and so it would never become eligible for finalization. - It seems it will, in fact, be GCed. The reason is that the class instance will have no other code referencing it, and the class itself doesn't access the UI or anything else. The system event is basically "swallowed" with no affects at all. So the GC might be smart enough to realize that and collect the class instance.

@Charlieface When it's not something that is used and discarded. It's an instance that is created and lives as a field, and is used by the app from time to time. Then at some point, by user action, or some other logic, it is decided that it isn't needed anymore.

@IvanPetrov Although system events seem not to have weak events, I can possibly work around that. Thanks, that a good idea.

@IvanPetrov * that's. (typo at the end of my comment)

@Iridium See my edit to the question, a link to an answer stating that the instance will be eligible for collection.

Then whatever holds that field should also be IDisposable and have a using. Ultimately something somewhere should be disposing this, or it should live in a static field and never be disposed.

@Charlieface should be disposing this - absolutely. But this code will be in a library and some callers might forget to do that. And notice that there is a difference between saying something should be disposed and saying it should be within a using statement.

Still sounds like you should be implementing the full Dispose pattern with a finalizer, which call Dispose to unhook the event.

@Charlieface Agreed. That's why I mentioned in the question Obviously one shouldn't rely on a destructor..

Neither of the answers you've linked are relevant to the scenario you describe. A static event such as SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged acts as a GC root, and an object with an event handler attached to such an event is therefore reachable from that GC root. Objects reachable from GC roots are "live" and so ineligible for garbage collection, and hence will not be finalized.

"At some point the class might not be referenced anymore and get garbage collected" - no, it will not, since the reference will be captured by the event via subscription. The linked in the edit answers do not work with events and missing unsubscribe is a go to way to get managed memory leak in .NET.

@GuruStron I know they don't deal with an event (if they would, I wouldn't have a question). The thing is they show how even when something seems to be alive, it can be collected. And I'm asking if the same will happen here. Though I'm now thinking that even if it can be GCd, it won't. Because there might not be a mechanism to auto-unsubscribe it so it will be removed from the subscription list of the event raiser.

hence the Weak Event Pattern that is supposed exactly this problem via Weak References

@IvanPetrov Yes. It does look like my best bet. You can transform your comment into an answer.

@ispiro I suspected this might be a duplicate - so just wanted to point you to something you might not be aware of. You can check my answer in your new question which demonstrates why is the instance not GCed.
