Will a class be garbage collected if it is subscribed to some event but does nothing with it?
Consider the following class which subscribes to an event but does nothing with it:
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;
    }

    void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            
    }
}

With an instance of said class created like this:
public class Runner
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();   
}

On the one hand, class1 is subscribed to an event, on the other, the runtime can easily deduce that there won't be any effect by it.
So, will class1 be eligible for garbage collection?

public class Runner ... - what is it? Runner's constructor? What is SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged?

Assuming that SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged is some static field or similar then no, until it will have the this.SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged unsubscribed then the instance of Class1 will not be collected even if there are none other references to it.

@GuruStron This is an extremely simplified example. I don't know how familiar you are with C# but the class above is compileable code. One does not need to explicitly write a constructor in C#. As for SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged - if you google it, the first result is to its docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?view=net-8.0

@GuruStron Please see the end of my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78737454/939213 after "EDIT". Objects are collectible if it can be shown they are not used. Perhaps the runtime is smart enough to understand that is the case here.

I'm kind of familiar with C# (you can check my profile =), though I'm not that familiar with WinAPI =) "but the class above is compileable code" - in current form it is not (if we take Runner into considiration). But that a nitpick) Thank you for providing link to the docs!

"Objects are collectible if it can be shown they are not used" - objects are collectible if they are not reachable from GC roots. Since SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged is an instance method then it requires a class instance (even if it does not use any other instance fields/methods), so it will make the instance reachable from the GC root - static event PowerModeChanged.

@GuruStron objects are collectible if they are not reachable from GC roots. - That's inexact. As I said in a comment above - see the answers I linked to there after "EDIT".

If variable is not used "after" executed part of the method it can be not considered as GC root by runtime, so this behavior does not make my statement incorrect.

Also none of the links apply to the case - SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged is not a local variable and it is a GC root (if with local variable you can see that it is not used, you can't do this with static event).

@GuruStron On a side note - why do you say that Runner is not compileable? And BTW I saw your profile, yes, you do seem quite knowledgeable in C# :)

"Runner is not compileable" - you are right, my bad, it is compilable, it is a bit late in the evening for me) Misread a bit - since there is another variable here, when the instance of Runner will go out of scope)

@GuruStron: Funny you have never heard of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged?view=net-8.0

@PoulBak thanks for the link, OP already provided it) As I wrote - have not worked that much with Win API)

No, it won't be garbage-collected because the static event acts as a root for the instance whose method is registered in the event delegate list.
If we want to demonstrate this, we can test by making use of the WeakReference class that keeps a weak reference to an instance that does not keep the object alive. It's nice to track the reachability/collectability of an instance.
So, the demo that needs to be compiled in Release mode and if you run on later .NET versions (also add <TieredCompilation>false</TieredCompilation> to .csproj) :
class A {
    public A() {
        StaticEventClass.StaticEvent += OnStaticEvent;
    }
    public void OnStaticEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Static event triggered");
    }

}

public class StaticEventClass {
    public static event EventHandler StaticEvent;
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
static void Main() {
    var a = new A();
    var wr = new WeakReference(a);
    a = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    Console.WriteLine(wr.IsAlive); // True
}

Comment/Delete the event-subscription in the constructor and the outcome is False.
You can really see how the event has a reference to our object if you decompile the constructor of A and specifically the event-subscription part:
    ...
    IL_0006: ldarg.0 // this - our instance
    IL_0007: ldftn instance void A::OnStaticEvent(object, class [System.Runtime]System.EventArgs)
    IL_000d: newobj instance void [System.Runtime]System.EventHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_0012: call void StaticEventClass::add_StaticEvent(class [System.Runtime]System.EventHandler)

In the third line we construct an instance of the EventHandler delegate that is used to "subscribe" to the event, i.e. added to the list of delegates maintained by the event.
newobj instance void [System.Runtime]System.EventHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
It takes two parameters which are given in the previous two lines:

ldarg.0 which is the this instance of A
ldftn gives us an unmanaged pointer to the OnStaticEvent instance method we are registering - native int

It is this delegate instance that keeps our object directly alive. Because it keeps a reference to the object it got through its constructor as an internal field - from source code of Delegate class.
public abstract partial class Delegate : ICloneable, ISerializable
{
    // _target is the object we will invoke on
    internal object? _target; // Initialized by VM as needed; null if static delegate

The static event just has a list of such delegate instances that the GC checks to determine the reachability of objects and their eligibility for garbage collection.

In .NET, the garbage collector (GC) cleans up objects that aren’t being used anymore. However, if an object is subscribed to an event, it’s a bit trickier.
When you subscribe to an event, your object (the subscriber) gets added to the event’s delegate list. This means the event publisher holds a reference to your object. As long as this reference exists, your object won’t be garbage collected, even if you set all other references to it to null.
Here’s a quick example to show what I mean:
public class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber(Publisher publisher)
    {
        publisher.SomeEvent += HandleEvent;
    }

    private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the event
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
    Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber(publisher);

    // Even after setting this to null, subscriber is still referenced by the event
    subscriber = null;

    // Subscriber won't be garbage collected as long as publisher is alive
}

In this example, even after setting the subscriber to null, the Subscriber object won’t be garbage collected because the Publisher object still holds a reference to it through the event.
You need to unsubscribe from the event when you’re done with the subscriber. Here’s one way to do it:
public class Subscriber : IDisposable
{
    private Publisher _publisher;

    public Subscriber(Publisher publisher)
    {
        _publisher = publisher;
        _publisher.SomeEvent += HandleEvent;
    }

    private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the event
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_publisher != null)
        {
            _publisher.SomeEvent -= HandleEvent;
            _publisher = null;
        }
    }
}

In this version, the Subscriber class implements IDisposable and unsubscribes from the event when disposed of. This way, the reference is removed, and the Subscriber object can be garbage collected.
So, to answer your question: no, a class won’t be garbage collected if it’s only referenced by an event subscription. You need to manually unsubscribe from the event to allow the GC to clean it up.

Generally speaking you are correct. But that is for a reason. Because the event handler might do something, e.g. when the event is fired, the event handler might update the UI. But here I'm asking about a case where the system can easily see that this is not the case. Hence the question.

There is no magic here, no deduction... Event keeps class reference since it points to its method

The publisher holds a reference to HandleEvent, which in turn holds a reference to the Subscriber instance. The garbage collector determines object reachability based on reference counts. As long as the publisher is alive and holds a reference to the subscriber through the event, the subscriber is considered reachable. The GC does not analyse the content of event handlers to determine their significance. It operates based on the presence of references alone.

Seems logical. Upvoted.

@ispiro you should really explore your comment "where the system can easily see" (into your method body). The "system" cannot experience your logic until it executes it, there is no magical read-ahead of the code and the compiler doesn't leave any hints that the method body is empty.

Side note: we can implement so called weak event patter to let GC collect instances even if they are subscribed for event(s) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/weak-event-patterns?view=netdesktop-8.0
